# MacOS Mojave - brew install mysql@5.7 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, homebrew, mysql-5.7, macos-mojave

When installing mysql via homebrew (i.e. `brew install mysql@5.7`) on MacOS Mojave,  a *seemingly* succesful installation prints the following instructions:

```
We've installed your MySQL database without a root password. To secure it run:
    mysql_secure_installation

MySQL is configured to only allow connections from localhost by default

To connect run:
    mysql -uroot
```

When `mysql -uroot`, or `mysql_secure_installation` is run, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

How can I login to `mysql` to change the password for `root`?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that using an "empty string" password via the `--password` flag solves this problem:

```
mysql -uroot --password=""
```

Alternatively, you can manually start `mysqld` with `--skip-grant-tables`:

```
$ mysql.server --skip-grant-tables
$ mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2
Server version: 5.7.24 Homebrew

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

$
```

And finally change the password with:

```
mysqladmin -uroot --password="" password NEW_PASSWORD
```

Comment: I am not sure how the default mysql password was set to "", but if others upvote this post (proving reproducibility), I will open a Pull Request against homebrew to try and fix this, or at least update the homebrew "Caveats" to include the "--password=''"

Answer (score 0):

After a new brew mysql install:

1) Make sure that mysql is running:  brew services start mysql

2) Change mysql password:  mysqladmin -uroot --password="" password 'NEWPASSWORD'

3) Secure mysql:  mysql_secure_installation (using new password)

Answer (score 0):

I think all people running the `mysql_secure_installation` command after installation would get into this trouble.

We need to append the username and password parameters to get thought this:

```
mysql_secure_installation -u root --password=""
```